SPA in Symfony UX Turbo
I am currently learning Symfony UX. My focus today was on UX Turbo. I basically wanted to create a very basic Single Page Application.

User can 'login' using a form, submitting the form should render the homescreen of the app.
The user can navigate the app and the selected screen should be displayed.
This all without any visible submitting or loading.

To achieve this Turbo has frames and streams. If I understand correctly frames can only update itself, while with streams you can edit/load/show different parts of the DOM.
I am using Twig as rendering engine, and my intent was to have a base-file with the outline of my application (logo, footer, navigation,...). This is my structure:

base.html.twig - outline of app with title, heading,...
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>{% block title %}Turbo app{% endblock %}</title>
        {% block stylesheets %}
            {{ encore_entry_link_tags('app') }}
        {% endblock %}
        {% block javascripts %}
            {{ encore_entry_script_tags('app') }}
        {% endblock %}
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>My Turbo App</h1>
        <turbo-frame id="app">
            {% block content %}{% endblock %}
        </turbo-frame>
    </body>
</html>


index.html.twig
{% extends '@web/base.html.twig' %}

{% block content %}
    <div id="login-screen">
        <h2>Login</h2>
        <turbo-frame id="form_frame">
            {{ form(form) }}
        </turbo-frame>
    </div>
{% endblock %}

{% block welcome_page_stream %}
    {% include '@web/pages/welcome.html.twig' %}
{% endblock %}


welcome.html.twig - Homescreen of the app, visible after successful authentication.
<turbo-stream action="update" targets="#app">
    <template>
        <h2>Welcome {{ name }}</h2>
        <p>You are successfully authenticated and can use the app now.</p>

        <a href="{{ path('app_random_page') }}" data-turbo-frame="advance">Click</a>
    </template>
</turbo-stream>


randompage.html.twig - An example of a screen in the app the user can navigate to.
<turbo-frame id="app">
    <h2>Random page</h2>
    <p>You clicked a button in the app and landed on this page without the page reloading.</p>
</turbo-frame>


I don't want to have one Twig file with all the screens/frames displayed. I want to have some kind of file structure to keep it maintainable.
These are the controllers:
class UserLoginShowController extends AbstractController
{
    #[Route('/login', name: 'app_login', methods: ['GET', 'POST'])]
    public function __invoke(Request $request): Response
    {

        $form = $this->createFormBuilder()
            ->add('name', TextType::class, ['label' => 'Your Name'])
            ->add('submit', SubmitType::class, ['label' => 'Submit'])
            ->getForm();

        $form->handleRequest($request);
        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            $request->setRequestFormat(TurboBundle::STREAM_FORMAT);
            $data = $form->getData();

            return $this->renderBlock('@web/index.html.twig', 'welcome_page_stream', ['name' => $data['name']]);
        }

        return $this->render('@web/index.html.twig', [
            'form' => $form->createView(),
        ]);
    }
}


class RandomPageController extends AbstractController
{
    #[Route('/some-action', name: 'app_random_page', methods: ['GET'])]
    public function __invoke(Request $request): Response
    {
        return $this->render('@web/pages/randompage.html.twig');
    }
}


Is this implementation okay? What can be improved? Maybe the project structure can be improved? Or the usage of Turbo streams vs frames? Maybe the index.html.twig is redundant and can be put in base.html.twig?
